# Why does '_cat/indices?v' return 403 Forbidden for Amazon OpenSearch Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, opensearch

I am running a simple `curl` request using Curl 8.3.0 to get info about indices in an Amazon OpenSearch cluster.

```bash
curl -XGET https://my_domain.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com/_cat/indices?v \
  --aws-sigv4 aws:amz:us-east-1:aoss \
  --user $AWS_ACCESS_KEY:$AWS_SECRET_KEY \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --header "x-amz-security-token:${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}"
```

However, I get a 403 Forbidden error:

```json
{"status":403,"request-id":"a6603a35-6757-9a13-86c9-xxx","error":{"reason":"403 Forbidden","type":"Forbidden"}}
```

Output of `curl -v`:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying x.x.x.x:443...
* Connected to my_domain.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Dec 18 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 16 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "my_domain.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "*.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/1.x
* Server auth using AWS_SIGV4 with user ''
> GET /_cat/indices?v HTTP/1.1
> Host: my_domain.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com
> Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=/20230927/us-east-1/aoss/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=ab....
> X-Amz-Date: 20230927T065937Z
> User-Agent: curl/8.3.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> x-amz-security-token:abc
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< x-request-id: 642feace-d1d2-9705-a97b-xxx
< x-aoss-response-hint: X01:gw-helper-deny
< content-type: application/json
< date: Wed, 27 Sep 2023 06:59:37 GMT
< content-length: 121
< server: aoss-amazon
< 
{"status":403,"request-id":"642feace-d1d2-9705-a97b-xxx","error":{"reason":"403 Forbidden","type":"Forbidden"}}
* Connection #0 to host my_domain.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com left intact
```

Here is my data access policy:

```json
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "ResourceType": "index",
      "Resource": [
        "index/my_collection/*"
      ],
      "Permission": [
        "aoss:CreateIndex",
        "aoss:DeleteIndex",
        "aoss:DescribeIndex",
        "aoss:ReadDocument",
        "aoss:UpdateIndex",
        "aoss:WriteDocument"
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceType": "collection",
      "Resource": [
        "collection/my_collection"
      ],
      "Permission": [
        "aoss:CreateCollectionItems",
        "aoss:DeleteCollectionItems",
        "aoss:DescribeCollectionItems",
        "aoss:UpdateCollectionItems"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Principal": [
    my_role_arn,
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe that's just copy/pasting, but the host in curl and python is not the same

Comment: @Val, thanks for pointing out.  That sure was a copy/paste error when I tried to hide my real domain.

Comment: Have you done echo for various variables like `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`? Can you hardcode everything to make sure the values are exactly the same for the script and Curl?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes I tried, and all variables are fine

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for the input, The python code and CURL is using the same IAM role which hold `aoss:*` permission. I'll add data access policy.

Comment: @RNA Does my answer below fix the issue for you?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks for your effortful answer.  Unfortunately, No, It did not help. `_cat/indices` and `_cat/indices?v=true` return the same 403 with `X01:gw-helper-deny`.

Comment: Very strange. Are you sure you’re assuming the credentials correctly for the right role? Does the output of `aws sts get-caller-identity` give the **exact** role ARN you’ve specified in the data access policy? Can you please generate a new set of creds and try that? If that fails, can you try creating a new cluster and call against that cluster with the same data access policy? How are you assuming the role? Something must be wrong here.

Comment: @RNA FYI if you don't reply to help us debug your issue, your current bounty will also expire again meaning your next one will have to be at least 400.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, role ARN-> the same as the role ARN in the data access policy. new cluster -> the same 403 error. the role is given from AWS SSO, how to assume -> with this method (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-legacy.html)

Comment: Thank you. Can you add the output of the command I pasted above and paste the full commands including terminal output to the question for how you’re assuming?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile my_profile` returns `{
    "UserId": "AXXXX...:myemail@mydomain.com",
    "Account": "myaccountID",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::myaccountID:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_myprofile_axxxxx.../myemail@mydomain.com"
}`

Answer (score 3):

Call `_cat/indices?v=true` instead.

This is a bug within OpenSearch Serverless & the `_cat/indices` endpoint. It incorrectly returns a 403 Forbidden, if you do not provide an actual boolean value for `v`.

| Endpoint | Amazon OpenSearch Serverless | Local OpenSearch Instance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_cat/indices` | ✅ 200 OK | ✅ 200 OK |
| `_cat/indices?v` | ❌ 403 Forbidden | ✅ 200 OK |
| `_cat/indices?v=false` | ✅ 200 OK | ✅ 200 OK |
| `_cat/indices?v=true` | ✅ 200 OK | ✅ 200 OK |

Amazon OpenSearch Serverless:

```bash
➜  ~ curl -XGET "https://xxx.eu-west-1.aoss.amazonaws.com/_cat/indices" \
          --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:eu-west-1:aoss" \
          --user "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY":"$AWS_SECRET_KEY" \
          --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
          --header "x-amz-security-token:${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 14
date: Wed, 18 Oct 2023 12:21:25 GMT
server: aoss-amazon-m
x-request-id: f8785ab2-e971-96f5-b7ce-0a613acf38c5

➜  ~ curl -XGET "https://xxx.eu-west-1.aoss.amazonaws.com/_cat/indices?v" \
          --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:eu-west-1:aoss" \
          --user "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY":"$AWS_SECRET_KEY" \
          --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
          --header "x-amz-security-token:${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" -i
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-request-id: ef2b256b-3bb2-9583-be96-86eb88f17660
x-aoss-response-hint: X01:gw-helper-deny
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 18 Oct 2023 12:21:28 GMT
content-length: 121
server: aoss-amazon

{"status":403,"request-id":"ef2b256b-3bb2-9583-be96-86eb88f17660","error":{"reason":"403 Forbidden","type":"Forbidden"}}

➜  ~ curl -XGET "https://xxx.eu-west-1.aoss.amazonaws.com/_cat/indices?v=false" \
          --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:eu-west-1:aoss" \
          --user "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY":"$AWS_SECRET_KEY" \
          --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
          --header "x-amz-security-token:${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 23
date: Wed, 18 Oct 2023 12:21:33 GMT
server: aoss-amazon-m
x-request-id: 9007beb6-17b0-9eb9-942c-22a2794a687f

➜  ~ curl -XGET "https://xxx.eu-west-1.aoss.amazonaws.com/_cat/indices?v=true" \
          --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:eu-west-1:aoss" \
          --user "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY":"$AWS_SECRET_KEY" \
          --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
          --header "x-amz-security-token:${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 83
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 35
date: Wed, 18 Oct 2023 12:21:37 GMT
server: aoss-amazon-m
x-request-id: da7599ca-c624-91fc-b964-a89c78463265

health status index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
```

Local Amazon OpenSearch:

```bash
➜  ~ curl -XGET "127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0

➜  ~ curl -XGET "127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 83

health status index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size

➜  ~ curl -XGET "127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v=false" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0

➜  ~ curl -XGET "127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v=true" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 83

health status index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
```